# Listview builder is constantly giving me null

Tags: json, flutter, api, rest, dart

I have this:

```
class HonPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Status? status;

  HonPage({Key? key, this.status}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HonPageState createState() {
    return _HonPageState();
  }
}

class _HonPageState extends State<HonPage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return new ListTile(
            title: new Text("${widget.status.title ?? ""}"),
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

My result:

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Whatever I do, I seem not to be able to fetch the items from `JSON`.

The JSON and API URL works on all other screens, so that can not be wrong. What am I doing wrong here? It's just that I have created a new tab and want to show the information.

Edit:
In **Status.dart**, I have this:

```
Status(Map<String, dynamic> json) : super(json) {
    status = json["status"];
    title = json["title"];
    ....
}
```

JSON:

```
[{"title": "NAME ME", "status": "publish"}]
```

Comment: It seems we are missing a lot of context here. JSON? Fetch Items? None of that is in your code...

Comment: What you're showing us has nothing to do with the problem you're having. The NULL values come from ${widget.status.title}, so show us how you're getting the data, where's status.title coming from

Comment: See edited post.

Comment: You still have not posted a line that indicates "widget.status.title" should *not* be null.

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: I think your JSON should be `[{"title": "NAME ME", "status": "publish"}]`. An array of JSON objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `FutureBuilder` when building a `ListView` to show results from an API call:

```
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<List<Status>>(
    future: fetchStatus(), // async API call that returns List<Status>
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return const Text("some error");
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Text("some error");
      }
      final list = snapshot.data as List<Status>;
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('${list[index].title ?? ""}'),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

**Updated:**

You have to create the following class:

```
class Status {
  final String title;
  final String status;

  const Status({
    this.title = '',
    this.status = '',
  });

  factory Status.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Status(
      title: json['title'] as String? ?? '',
      status: json['status'] as String? ?? '',
    );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
      'title': title,
      'status': status,
    };
}
```

You have to write the method `fetchStatus` to call the API and return `List<Status>`.

**Updated 2**

```
return ListTile(
  title: Text('${list[index].title ?? ""}'),
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      '/detail_page',
      arguments: list[index],
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't get it. It's giving me errors on snapshot and Error: 'Status' isn't a type.
        final list = snapshot.data as List<Status>;
                                           ^^^^^^
lib/src/views/sfa.dart:44:15: Error: The method 'fetchStatus' isn't defined for the class

Comment: I have updated the answer above to include sample for the `Status` data class but you have to provide the method `fetchStatus` yourself. It should return `Future<List<Status>>`.

Comment: Roslan, where do I put the URL of my API?

Comment: See my answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69832046/how-to-call-rapid-api-and-show-in-the-flutter-application/69834832?noredirect=1#comment123492030_69834832. See class `APIService`.

Comment: Clear. What about going to the detail page of the post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69800298/how-to-get-to-the-detail-page-of-my-posts-flutter-rest

Comment: On the `ListTile`, add the `onTap` argument. This is a function where you can use the Navigator to push to the `DetailPage` passing in `list[index]` as the `argument`.

Comment: I did.                         onTap: () {
                          widget.handleOpenPlace!(places![index]);
                        },  - however this does not do anything :(

Comment: See my latest update. You have to use `Navigator.push` or `Navigator.pushNamed`. See the link I gave above on how to create the detail page using Navigator.

Comment: Pushnamed is when you have a URL (like detail_page) to state?  I don't have that.  I have the use handleOpenPlace. And assuming list = places for me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238934/discussion-between-roslan-amir-and-johan).