# How to get to the detail page of my posts flutter / REST?

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dart

I am constantly getting the same error:

> The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture: Null
> check operator used on a null value

I tried everything here:
final void Function(Place)? handleOpenPlace;

Removed the question mark `?` and added `required`: **did not work**

```
  final void Function(Place)? handleOpenPlace; // open place with id
  final List<Place>? places;
  CustomListTileView({Key? key, this.handleOpenPlace, this.places}) : super();
  final String apiURL = 'https://mywebsite/api/';

  Future<List<ParseJSON>> fetchJSON() async {
    var jsonResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiURL));

    if (jsonResponse.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonItems =
      json.decode(jsonResponse.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

      List<ParseJSON> tempList = jsonItems.map<ParseJSON>((json) {
        return ParseJSON.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();

      return tempList;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed To Load Data');
    }
  }
```

Places being a list in `Place.dart`

And here:

```
widget.handleOpenPlace!(places![index]);
```

- Removed the `!`, but did not work.
- Added `?`, but did not work
- Tried
  changing them all: did not work

The full Card code:

```
          return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  items[index].name.toString(),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  widget.handleOpenPlace!(places![index]);
                },
                subtitle: Text(
                  items[index].email.toString(),
                ),
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  child: Text(items[index].name.toString()[0],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 21.0,
                      )),
                ),
              ));
```

What am I doing wrong here? Listing the posts works, but the moment I want to go to the detail page, it fails.

Comment: Try reducing the use of bang `!`  operator. I still miss parts from your code, what is the `places` variable ? Obviously you are getting the error from `onTap`, and means that either `handleOpenPlace` function is `null` or `places` is `null`.

Comment: This is places:   final List<Place>? places; Does that work? I don't know how I could make it not null...

Comment: Can you show the `CustomListTileView` implementation ?

Comment: I did, it's in the post or do you need something specific?

Comment: I mean show me how you call it, I want to see how you pass the parameters.

Comment: Done, check please @esentis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try making `handleOpenPlace` & `places` `required`?

```dart
final void Function(Place) handleOpenPlace; // open place with id
final List<Place> places;
CustomListTileView({Key? key,required this.handleOpenPlace,required this.places}) : super();
```

And remove the bangs `!` from the `onTap`

```dart
onTap: () {
 widget.handleOpenPlace(places[index]);
},
```

This way you will be safer to `null` and at least you can tackle the source of the `null` cast.

Comment: That gives me: Error: Required named parameter 'handleOpenPlace' must be provided and: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.

Comment: Yes this is normal because you now have to provide those when you first create your `CustomListTileView`. I still can't see how you call the widget, `CustomListTileView(places:..., handleOpenPlace:...)`.